# Iterating through range between strings

Tags: python, dictionary, range

**Set-up**

Using [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/), I am scraping housing ads. Per housing ad, I obtain a postal code.

I have a dictionary linking postal codes to districts,

```
postal_district = {'A': ['1011AB', '1011BD', '1011BG', '1011CE',
                         '1011CH', '1011CZ', '1011DB', '1011DD']}
```

The entire dictionary can be viewed [here](http://chopapp.com/#pwipjzr9).

Each two subsequent postal codes in the list form a range – the first postal code is the min of the range, the second postal code is the max.

E.g. any postal code in

`'1011AB', '1011AC',...,'1011AZ', '1011BA',...,'1011BD'`

belongs to district `'A'`.

My goal is to match ads to districts via their postal code and the dictionary.

---

**Problem**

I've asked a preceding question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43975616/7326714) and have chosen to follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43976696/7326714) to solve the issue.

Thus, I am using the following code to match the ads to districts,

```
def is_in_postcode_range(current_postcode, min, max):
     return min <= current_postcode <= max

def get_district_by_post_code(postcode):
     for district, codes in postal_district.items():
         first_code = codes[0]
         last_code = codes[-1]
         if is_in_postcode_range(postcode, first_code, last_code):
             if any(is_in_postcode_range(postcode, codes[i], codes[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(codes), 2)):
                 return district
             else:
                 return None

district = get_district_by_post_code(pc)
```

For some postal codes this works. However, many postal codes are not matched. 
`1035CK`, `1072LL`, `1059EC` are unmatched, to name a few.

---

What is wrong? Is it the dictionary or the code?

I've sorted the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This construct:

```
 if is_in_postcode_range(postcode, first_code, last_code):
     if any(is_in_postcode_range(postcode, codes[i], codes[i+1]) 
             for i in range(0, len(codes), 2)):
         return district
     else:
         return None
```

Assumes that the postal districts have no overlapping ranges.  If that is not true, then you need to remove:

```
else:
    return None
```

Comment: I'll be damned.